# Failed in connecting to remote sql database using domain name instead of hardcoded remote ip address

Tags: python, django

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['http://xxx.xxxx.com/']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'xxxxDB',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    }
```

tried replacing the remote ip to domain name which is in working state,django stops connecting doesnt show any error.please help.